# Azure DevOps Pipeline agent fails while running Terraform Plan with UnAuthorized error while connecting to a Storage Account

Tags: azure, networking, devops, azure-storage-account

I have a storage account which has

a) Microsoft network routing selected. 
b) Publish route-specific endpoint as only Microsoft network routing enabled.

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline agent running terraform plan - before running a plan I get the public ip of the VM (using curl) and run bash script to add thise public ip of the VM to the Network ACL of the storage account.
However the plan fails with not authorized error.

As soon as I also select the "Publish Internet routing" the plan starts working.
Can anyone shed light/explain why this is happening ?

PS: attaching the error details from pipeline..

```
Error: Error retrieving Container "bootdiag" (Account "xxxxxxxxx" / Resource Group "xx-dev-xx-xxx-001"): containers.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:f01c457e-d01e-0036-38b5-f25ba0000000\nTime:2021-01-25T00:57:41.2404471Z"
```

Comment: Could you show the specific error message that the plan fails with not authorized error.

Comment: I have added the error message details now at the end of the post.

Comment: Could you double-check that you only extra select the "Publish Internet routing" the plan starts working? When you publish route-specific endpoints, Azure Storage creates new public endpoints for your storage account that route traffic over the desired path. If you still use the original endpoint of the storage account, there should be no change.

Comment: Is this issue fixed on your side? If so, please share the answer.

Comment: i have had the chance to retest this yet. will get back